# How to reinstall requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, github, requirements.txt

I'm working in this shared Django project, a colleague is the owner of the repo in Github. The problem I am facing right now is that he added **raven** to his packages and in github the requirements.txt file is updated, however when I tried with git pull, locally, my requirements.txt does not have **raven** added. He told me that I have to reinstall requirements.txt so I tried with pip freeze > requirements.txt but nothing change.

How can I update my requirements.txt file according the updates made from Github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pull all changes to your local repository.
To do that, you need to make sure that your git repository don't have any active changes.

```
git commit -am "changes"
git pull
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

After you've pulled the latest changes into your requirements.txt, you can absolutely rerun pip.  Run the command with `pip install -r requirements.txt` and it will install any new modules.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the requirements.txt is not inside the .gitignore file, which will prevent it from being updated.